# How to run jar inside SBT task?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a simple [project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf5TC.png)
There is a packaged `my.jar` inside `lib` directory.

And i have a task in `build.sbt` as well

```
TaskKey[Unit]("myTask") := {
    // Evaluates some actions here

    // After all actions was evaluated, 
    // my.jar with some arguments,
    // e.g. -a1 argument1 -a2 argument2,
    // migth be executed
}
```

How to run `my.jar` in a task with some arguments?

**P.S.** Sorry for my English, it's not my native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my.jar` can be executed in the task using `Process` class . It takes two parameter, one being a `List` of `String` making up the command to be executed and the second parameter setting the current working directory as shown below.

```
TaskKey[Unit]("myTask") := {
  Process("java" :: "-jar" :: "my.jar" :: "-a1" :: "argument" :: "-a2" :: "argument" :: Nil,
    (baseDirectory.value / "lib")).!
}
```

Comment: I feel the answer is out there. I got `Error: Unable to access jarfile my.jar`

Comment: my filename contained `-`. I just renamed without `-` and it works!